# Point-Biserial Correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have sample data (230 records) that looks like this:

```
Salary  Success - Failure
23,300  1
44,000  1
12,400  0
23,000  1
55,000  0
    …
Success =1  

Fail = 0
```

I am trying to correlate a continuous variable (salary) with a binary one (Success -Failure – dependent)
I need a sample R –code for the above data set using Point-Biserial Correlation.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your `data.frame` is `df`:

```
X = df$Salary
Y = df[,2]

a = sqrt(sum(Y)*(1-sum(Y))/(length(Y)**2))

point.bis.corr = a*(mean(X[Y==1])-mean(X[Y==0]))/sd(X)
```

Comment: Colonel Beauvel - Thanks for your quick help

Comment: you can tick the mark if this answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

if dataframe name is df

```
biserial.cor(Salary,Success, level=2)
```

or

```
X = df$Salary
Y = df$Success

a = sqrt(sum(Y)*(length(Y)-sum(Y))/(length(Y)**2))

point.bis.corr = a*(mean(X[Y==1])-mean(X[Y==0]))/sd(X)

point.bis.corr
```

Comment: As you're answering a post from 4 years ago, it would be good if you could elaborate on why your solution improves the answers already given.